# TIKZ: writing text top downwards

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

My simple question is how to set some text using tikz in a column e.g.

```
+---+
| A |
| B |
| C |
+---+
```

I do not want to rotate the text so I can not use the rotate option or the set text along path method. Can give me a hint how to do it right?

Comment: Using a matrix and populating the rows with letters maybe?

Comment: Then I need the size and position of the whole matrix.

Comment: Just about anything can go in a `\node` text so you could achieve this with `\node[align=center] {A \\ B \\ C};` (the `align` is needed to ensure that the `\\\` are taken note of).

Comment: @Christian: Do you need a way of writing long strings of text that way, or would a "manual" approach like the one Andrew mentioned work for your application?

Comment: The strings are some characters long. Single words like entry, vip or staff. I'll try these days. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was/am ill. That would be ok, but again: Then I need the size of the node. I want to add a background to it which is some sort of rectangle plus a half ellipse. The size I can adjust manually but that's ugly. Also creating a shape for the node seems a bit too much effort for two small symbols.

Comment: @Andrew: You should turn your comment into an answer so this can be closed?

Comment: @Peter: As requested, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comments, just about anything is allowed in a `node`; in particular, multi-line text.  The only thing is that the node needs to know how to vertically align the text.  This is controlled by the `align` key (Section 16.4.3 in the PGF manual (PGF2.10)).  In the following, I've chosen `center`.  Getting the size of the node after is simple using the anchors.  To ensure that the anchors are big enough that the resulting shape will be clear of the text, I chose an ellipse as the node shape.  As you say, it may not be worth designing a whole new shape just for one symbol, so I've drawn something vaguely like what you describe manually.  In order to get the arc right, I wrote a little helper macro that measures the distance between two points.  This is because arcs are specified using radii, but we want to draw an arc between certain points.  So we measure the points first and use the measurements to specify the radii.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26028/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\measure}[2]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \pgf@xa=-\pgf@x\relax
  \pgf@ya=-\pgf@y\relax
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#2\relax
  \advance\pgf@x by \pgf@xa\relax
  \advance\pgf@y by \pgf@ya\relax
  \edef\xdistance{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef\ydistance{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,ellipse] (a) {this\\is\\some\\text\\arranged\\vertically};
\measure{(a.west)}{(a.north)}
\draw (a.east) |- (a.north) -| (a.west) arc[x radius=\xdistance, y radius=\ydistance, start angle=-180, end angle=0];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: vertical text in a node]